# is it possible to open the safari browser from my application instead of using a UIWebview component

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Does anyone know if it's possible to open the safari browser with a static link , instead of using a UIWebview component.

If so how can i realize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenURL](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:) can open many things, http and https are registered with safari.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]];
```